# Reshaping R dataframe (compute average of a column based on multiple 'level' columns)

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, reshape, data-manipulation

I have a R dataframe with this type of structure (Dummy example):

```
df 

A B C D
1 a 3 5
1 a 5 3
1 b 2 8
2 a 4 7
2 a 6 5
2 b 4 3

...
```

"A", "B", "C", and "D" are column headers.

I want to reshape this dataframe so that I get average(mean) of "C" and "D" by each level of "A" and "B".

So the final product I want would be:

```
new_df

A BaC BbC BaD BbD 
1  4   2   4   8
2  5   4   6   3
```

I managed to do it in a very crude way:

```
spread_df_C <- spread(df, B, C)
aggregated_df_C <- aggregate(spread_df$a, list(spread_df$A), mean)

spread_df_D <- spread(df, B, D)
aggregated_df_D <- aggregate(spread_df$a, list(spread_df$A), mean)

new_df <- merge(aggregated_df_C, aggregated_df_D, by=c("A", "A")
```

This would get me the final product eventually, but I am laboriously computing mean for each of the levels. I need to do this for several levels, and there has to be more elegant way of executing it.

Experts, please help

Answer (score 1):

An option using the `reshape2` package.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(dat, measure.vars = c("C", "D")), A ~ B + variable, fun.aggregate = mean)
#  A a_C a_D b_C b_D
#1 1   4   4   2   8
#2 2   5   6   4   3
```

The first step is to `melt` columns `C` and `D` and then cast the resulting  dataframe back to wide format.

Answer (score 1):

Consider base R's `reshape` after aggregation and switch of column name before/after period:

```
agg <- aggregate(. ~ A + B, df, mean)
rdf <- reshape(agg, idvar = "A", timevar = "B",  direction = "wide")

names(rdf)[-1] <- paste0("B", substr(names(rdf)[-1], 3, 3), substr(names(rdf)[-1], 1, 1))

rdf
#   A BaC BaD BbC BbD
# 1 1   4   4   2   8
# 2 2   5   6   4   3
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, val, -c(1:2)) %>%
 group_by_at(1:3) %>%
 summarise(val = mean(val)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(var = paste(var, B, sep = "_")) %>%
 select(-2) %>%
 spread(var, val)

      A   C_a   C_b   D_a   D_b
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4     2     4     8
2     2     5     4     6     3
```